# Overriding MenuItem ControlTemplate prevents the ContextMenu from closing when an item is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

I'm using WPF and overriding the `ControlTemplate` of a `MenuItem` like this:

```xml
<Button Content="Click Me" Margin="5">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Button Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=DataContext.MenuItemCommand}">
                            <TextBlock Text="Item 1" Margin="5"/>
                        </Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuItem.Template>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

My context menu opens just fine and when I click the item it activates the button's command just fine, but the context menu does not close. Any suggestions on what I need to do to get the context menu to close after an item is clicked?

Comment: What did you want to achieve by overriding the control template of `MenuItem`?

Comment: I wanted to hide the left icon "column"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Button` from the template and handle the `Command` of the `MenuItem` itself:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Margin="5">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding MenuItemCommand}">
                <MenuItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Item 1" Margin="5"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuItem.Template>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide default background of `MenuItem` you can style it like this:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Margin="5">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border Name="bdr" Margin="-5" Padding="10" Background="White">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=Header}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="bdr" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Item 1" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=DataContext.MenuItemCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```